# Is there a way to gain recursive read access to a a user specified folder in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

If I'm operating within the Sandbox clearly I can't just start randomly reading from the HDD.  Is there a way for the user to open up access to a folder including all its sub folders without using full trust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no.

The long answer is: no you can't.  The closest you can get (which is still miles away from what you want) is showing the user a OpenFileDialog and letting them select multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Just to toss out the info if it helps...

This should be possible in Silverlight 5, but I don't think it is in the Silverlight 5 Beta that was released at Mix this year.  Here is one of my co-workers, Nick Kramer, [giving a demo of it working](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/MED12) (with code):

Comment: Silverlight 5 does allow more, *but* the OP said 'without using full trust' which rules it out.